# What are good deep learning papers for self-driving cars?

Tags: machine-learning, references, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I do deep learning for self-driving car for my graduation project. I need some advice and recommendations about the deep learning part in self-driving cars. Among all those published data, what data should I choose?

Comment: Answering the question probably requires expertise on self-driving cars rather than statistics, so I am not sure this is on topic here. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @RichardHardy i didn't put statistics as a tag

Comment: You don't need the tag -- this is a statistics forum in the first place.